# Scraping online maps

Tags: r, web-scraping, geospatial

I am trying to find a way to scrape the protected areas spatial polygons from this website:http://datazone.birdlife.org/site/factsheet/adamello-brenta-iba-italy/map. However, I didn't figure out yet how to do it. Has someone suggestions how to start the process? Possibly in R or QGIS environments.

Comment: http://datazone.birdlife.org/species/requestdis

Comment: I know that I can request it. My idea was to automatically scrape all EU IBAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That server provides [WFS access](http://birdlaa8.miniserver.com/geoserver/ows?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities) as well as the WMS so you can simply download the data using a URL like:

```
http://birdlaa8.miniserver.com:8080/geoserver/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=birdlife_dz:IbaMapGlobal_POL_wm_20200930_selected&TYPENAME=birdlife_dz:IbaMapGlobal_POL_wm_20200930_selected
```

You can choose any of these output formats:

```
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>GML2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>KML</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>SHAPE-ZIP</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/json</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/vnd.google-earth.kml xml</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>csv</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>gml3</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>gml32</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>json</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
```

by adding `&outputformat=csv` to the end of the url.